# How to remove global FocusVisualStyle to all the Controls?

Tags: wpf

I met the same problem as [Deactivate FocusVisualStyle globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055670/deactivate-focusvisualstyle-globally).

But none of the answers can work.

So, I just want to set all the Controls in my application `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"`, any 
effecive way to achieve this?

I don't want to set each control separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deactivate FocusVisualStyle globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055670/deactivate-focusvisualstyle-globally)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about just putting this into your `Application.Resources`?:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```

To also affect non-controls as well, try this instead:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```

As `Control` is derived from `FrameworkElement`, they will all use this `Style` also.

Comment: I did post such a question.  But I left the comment above w/ good intentions, to alert others that this is not a universal solution.  I am not the only one who leaves such comments.

Comment: If I posted an answer that I thought was general but which turned out to be wrong in some unknown number of cases, I'd want to know about that.