# Prevent Rectangle Style From Applying to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `style` set in my `app.config` that I want to colour every `rectangle` I use in my program. It's nice and simple, it looks like this;

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightBlue"/>
</Style>
```

I noticed some weird behaviour in all of my `DataGrids` recently in that when the user navigated through the `rows` using the arrow keys, the text inside the cell would be blanked out, it looks like this;

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER ARROWKEYS PRESSED**

[image]

As you can see the text is quite clearly gone (that's the same cell in both images). I finally got round to looking at this and came to the conclusion that the `rectangle` style is applying to each `DataGridCell`. I can only assume that that is because `wpf` uses `recangles` in a `DataGridCell`.

Is there a way I can apply this style to only the `rectangles` that I have taken out of the toolbox and not the literal `rectangles` in the `DataGrid`?

An easy option out of this is to remove the `style` completely and individually apply it, but if we change the colour scheme further down the line this could become very time consuming.

**UPDATED**

I'd also (if possible) like to use any fix in conjuction with modifying my `DataGridCell` appearance which I do like so;

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridCells` use `FocusVisualStyle` which has Rectangle in its visual tree. Those rectangles get `Fill` brush from default Rectangle style. If you change `FocusVisualStyle`, cells become visible on keyboard selection

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

if there is already a default style for `DataGridCell`, add a setter there

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/> 
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

additional info: I have the same issue with `Buttons` and selection using `Tab`

Comment: Hi ash, I've updated my question. Your fix does work in keeping the text however it (as I would expect) removes the style that I would like to apply to the `DataGridCell`. Is there a way of being able to do both?

Comment: Apologies for bringing up an old (ish) thread.. but now when I am doing something such as `dataGrid.Focus()` the entire `DataGrid` is being filled LightBlue. I assume again that rectangle is used within `DataGrid` somehow, is there a way to prevent this from happening? Also as you stated in your answer I am also having this issues when tabbing through `Buttons` as well. How did you manage to get around the `Button` issue?

Comment: @CBreeze, looks like it is their `FocusVisualStyle` again, which is basically a rectangle, but *without default Fill value*. this post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055670/deactivate-focusvisualstyle-globally